# Windows store app compilation errors after changing the target CPU

Tags: xaml, bing-maps, windows-store-apps, anycpu, target-platform

I wanted to add a Bing maps feature to my windows store app,
which already runs perfectly. The problem is, that to add Bing maps, i have to change the 
running project configuration from 'any CPU' to ARM, x86 or x64.

Once i do that all hell breaks loose, and i get errors indicating unfound different resources that i use in my XAML.
I followed all the steps according to this article 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408457/Using-Bing-Maps-For-Windows-8-Metro-Apps-Csharp-Ja

I'm trying to change the platform to 'x64'.
Any ideas?

Comment: Well, didn't figure out the errors yet, 
but i just changed the target CPU of the project that uses Bing Maps to 'x64',
and left the others on 'Any CPU', and the app runs perfectly fine, with my dandy maps feature.
when i'll figure out the errors, i'll update.

Comment: How about posting the errors here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because Bing maps does not support all platforms except ARM x86 or x64 . It is mainly built for Navigation purpose which is supported in tablets which has ARM processors.